# How can I manipulate this data with using for loops in R

Tags: r, dplyr

[image: sample data]

I have a problem about manipulation of a data in R. What I need in this job is to manipulate data via sample-data in the link. When I tried to do this I tried to use dplyr package but it didn't work. So I want to do it using for-loop.

What I want is exactly this:

I want to keep the A, B, C, D, E categories fixed and put the data of the months that are next to them. Like January 1990, February 1990, ...., December 1990, January 1991, February 1991, ..., December 1991. These months will be side by side and will be in column form. Since there is no data for certain categories in some years, it should give a value of "0" in the months corresponding to those categories. How should I write a for loop for this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please provide your data with `dput` not images.

Comment: please provide your data in a reproducible manner, such as doing `dput(data)` and pasting the result. If it is too long, you can try `dput(head(data))`

Comment: Are you saying you only want 5 rows, then a column for every month / year combination? If so, I would actually avoid using a forloop and keep using dplyr. You can use `dplyr::gather` on the data to have 4 columns: the year, the category, the month and the data value. Then you can use a `mutate` to create a new variable, `dplyr::mutate(year_month = paste0(year,"-",month))`, then use `dplyr::spread` to get the output your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using a fake of your picture I wrote the following. Let me know if the output is ac This is similar to rfortin's suggestion but with `data.table` instead of `dplyr`.

**Code:**

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- melt(data, id.vars = c("Year", "Category"), measure.vars = c("Jan", "Feb"), 
           variable.name = "Month", value.name = "Profit") %>%
  .[, `Month-Year`:= paste(`Month`, `Year`, sep = " ")] %>%
  dcast(., `Category` ~ `Month-Year`, fun.aggregate = sum, value.var = "Profit")
```

**Data:**

```r
data <- data.table(Year = c(1999,1999,1999,2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001), 
                   Category = c("A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C","A", "B", "C"), 
                   Jan = c(234234,3413,134,134,13423,1324,1324,1235,54), 
                   Feb = c(234523,435234,0,2342,0,153,24,234,72))
```

**Output:**

```r
   Category Feb 1999 Feb 2000 Feb 2001 Jan 1999 Jan 2000 Jan 2001
1:        A   234523     2342       24   234234      134     1324
2:        B   435234        0      234     3413    13423     1235
3:        C        0      153       72      134     1324       54
```